# What is the name convention for graphql schema?

Tags: graphql

I am using graphql and I'd like to know there is standard naming convention for mutation/query/subscription.

Is it fine if I name it like:

```
mutation {
   createOrGetUUID() # create a uuid if not exit, otherwise return the existing one
}

query {
   uuid() # query uuid
}
```

my concern is about the mutation `createOrGetUUID`. It does two jobs, one is to create, the other is to get. What should I name this method? It sounds like this method does both `mutation` and `query`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply hide this feature (business/internal logic) under simple query [resolver] as not [real] update/explicit mutation.

```
query {
  uuid() # returns current uuid, creates new one if not exists
}
```

This method is often used to update changed record structures on read (without updating all records/whole db/table.

Comment: based on my understand, `query` should not update anything on the backend. otherwise it is hard to read and maintain. Just like `get` and `post` in rest world.

Comment: and you belive that get only reads data, always, everywhere? this is a part of maintance, auto-fixing, without introducing additional, not really required [externally] mutations ... you can even write `uuid() # returns current uuid` leaving backend 'mystery' hidden/undocummented - ask backenders for advice